# Apply boolean mask to Scala array

Tags: arrays, scala, bitmask

I'm trying to use an array of booleans to choose particular elements in another array. For example:

```
val arr = Seq("A", "B", "C")
val mask = Seq(true,false,true)
```

and I'd like the output to be a new array:

```
val arr_new = Seq("A","C")
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Scala?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
scala> arr.zip(mask).collect { case (v, true) => v }
res0: Seq[String] = List(A, C)
```

Comment: cool! just learnt that partial function is a combination of map and filter i.e. all values that are not valid arguments to the partial function are ignored.

Comment: @Samar It isn't a partial function which is the combination of `map` and `filter`. It's `collect`, and it's specifically defined to ignore elements on which its argument is not defined. Other methods which accept partial functions can do other things in this case.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov:  from the docs for collect: `def
collect[B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): Array[B]` collect accepts a partial function, thats what I meant.

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you mean. Collect is specially designed to ignore unapplicable arguments to the supplied partial function.